# Bound Column in ASP Grid view when invisible cannot be accessed

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundcolumn

I have a GridView with BoundColumns. The first 2 columns are hidden and I would like to access them using gridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text and gridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text respectively and I get a empty string. When the columns are changed to visible, then I can access the values.
I have tried changing the column width to zero as suggested on some other forums but that never fixed the problem. Does any one have any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Columns are part of the `DataKeyNames` collection, then you should get their values from the `GridView.DataKeys[index].value` property, as demonstrated on the [GridViewGuy site](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/87_Accessing%20Invisible%20Columns%20of%20GridView%20Control.aspx).

If however, they are not part of the `DataKeyNames` collection, then you can use the following hack to make sure that the value is persisted in ViewState (as opposed to normal behaviour for hidden fields in ASP.NET 2+)

```
GridView1.DataSource = myDataSource;
// Set the column visibility to true before Databinding

GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
GridView1.DataBind()

// Set the column visibility to false after Databinding
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is typical behaviour in ASP.NET, Visible = false, only makes the control available in code-behind.

The best for this would be to apply the following style on that column:

```
display:'none'
```

Comment: Given that it's rendered as a table in html, which is row oriented, can you set a display:none style on a column? I'm not saying you can't, I just have never tried it!
Would it render the display:none style on each td cell in the column?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I wonder... it will probably place the style on the TD, not sure if that will work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the css class `hiddencol` to the column you want to hide. Add `hiddencol` class to your css and you're good to go.

You can still access the column in your code behind but it isn't displayed on your page.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Site_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />

.hiddencol
{
    display: none;
}
```